# Fan controller for a high-end PC?

Tags: fan-controller, desktop

I'm looking for a fan controller suitable for a high-end PC with the following specs (all are required):

- 5.25" form factor
- Material is either completely or partially metal
- At least 4 fan channels
- Temperature alarm system
- Touchscreen display
- Profiles/presets for storing settings
- Shows fan speeds and voltages
- Grayscale color
- Can take up more than one front slot

And then there's the design. I'd prefer it to look sleek and minimalistic with an easy-to-quickly-glance-at display.

Price isn't an issue.

Comment: What color would you like it to be. Also, can it take up more than 1 5.25 inch slot?

Comment: @Firepower0701 Anything grayscale is good. Not a huge fan of color on a PC. And yes it can take up more than one slot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If having physical controls on the front of your PC isn't hugely important to you and you are running Windows on your PC, how about a USB fan controller like the [NZXT Grid Plus v2](https://www.nzxt.com/product/detail/157-GRID-V2-digital-fan-controller.html)?

[image: NZXT Grid Plus v2 image]

Up to 6 fans, uses the temperature sensors already inside your components so you won't need to wire your own in, multiple profiles, custom temperature curves, up to 6 fans, and it all runs off a box that you can just sit somewhere hidden in your case. Also, it's only around $30.

As for the CAM software which you use to control the GRID, I have been using it with my NZXT Kraken x61 cooler, and it seems stable, albeit a little bit bloated with ~100MB RAM usage.

I know this isn't what you specifically asked for, but it may be worth exploring?

Comment: Interesting recommendation. It definitely isn't what I was originally looking for, but it could work.

Answer (score 4):

With the information given, I would recommend the NZXT Sentry 3 or Sentry 2 fan controller. You can buy one [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00KJGYLNM). The reviews are good, the only cons being that sometimes the controller does not work out of the box and that it is easy to make a mess out of the cables. The LED touch screen is of good quality as well.

Comment: Have you used this fan controller? What kind of problem occurs out of the box and how easy is it to fix?

Comment: No, I have not used this fan controller. I have read, however, that cableing can be a menace, that the touch screen is responsive, and some units do not work out of the box.

Comment: Why was my answer immediately down voted after receiving best answer. Feedback on why my answer was bad is way more useful than just down voting it. I haven't used stack exchange for all that long, so I really would appreciate some insight on how I can improve my answers.

Comment: I provided the downvote. I mentioned your answer [here](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/163/57), but the TL;DR is that the quality here could be improved greatly. A [meta post](http://meta.hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/59/what-is-required-for-an-answer-to-be-high-quality) was created with suggestions on how to provide a high quality answer. If you could address some of the concerns I mentioned in my post and take a look at the other one, I'd be more than happy to reverse the down vote.